# A way to store time without seconds in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, time

I want to save time in my SQL Server database in this format:

```
hh:mm
```

and not this:

```
hh:mm:ss
```

Is that possible? Is there a unique data type for that (I tried to go over the list of data types but failed to find; tried also to search on MSDN and didn't find). Is there another way? I really do not want the second to be stored.

Comment: it is always stored the only thing you can do is to edit the value before it gets posted so the seconds (and also the milliseconds which are also stored) are set to 0

Comment: @GuidoG - thanks. I think you should put it in an answer...

Comment: Just store it as a datetime with the seconds set to zero. Why don't you want the seconds stored anyway?

Comment: @RichBenner Because that is data that I do not need, and I do not want data I do not need on my database...

Comment: `LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),108),5)`

Comment: @JaydipJ - could you please put it in an answer and elaborate?

Comment: @Sipo:108 returns only time part from datetime and you use left to restrict output

Comment: I suggest you to use two columns for: `Hour` & `Minute` ;).

Comment: @TheGameiswar - yes but I do not want to format the output... Just stored it correctly..

Comment: @shA.t - that is a very creative solution I think. You should put it in an answer...

Comment: @Sipo as per TheGameiswar comment, this is enough description for given statement , and can you add how you are passing time values to database

Comment: I think you could also write a trigger on tthat table that overwrites seconds and milliseconds to zero but they will still be stored offcourse

Comment: @JaydipJ - I use a simple `INSERT INTO`

Comment: @Sipo Can you please add your `INSERT` query ?

Comment: @JaydipJ `INSERT INTO table (time) VALUES ("15:30")`

Comment: @Sipo I have Ans below Please find below Ans and let me know if it is helpful for you?

Answer (score 7):

Use [Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213505.aspx) function available from SQL Server 2012

```
select format(getdate(),'hh:mm')

Insert into sometable
(timepart)
values
(
format(getdate(),'hh:mm'))
```

**Output:**

07:08

Comment: Only in sql server +2012

Comment: Thanks... But I want to store it without seconds in the first place.

Comment: This stores only hours and minutes part of datetime

Comment: @TheGameiswar - that is a `select`... Or am I wrong? I mean, isn't a select just the way to ge data from the database? And then the `format` just format it to be `hh:mm`? If yes, it is not what I need... I need it to be stored at the first place as `hh:mm`... Thanks.

Comment: @Sipo: while inserting also you can use

Answer (score 6):

No there isn't a data type for this.  The smallest is [time(0)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187752.aspx), which is accurate to one second.

```
SELECT
    -- Returns time in the format hh:mm:ss
    CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME(0))
;
```

You could add a [check constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190377.aspx) to ensure the seconds are always equal to 00, but I'm not sure what value this would add.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using SQL-Server 2008+ , you can use the [`TIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) type and just reset the seconds and just ignore them while selecting.

If not, you can consider saving them as strings(extract the HH:MI) or integers(counting minutes after 00:00). Like @destination-data said, you should note that you won't be able to use the time functions available for SQL-Server, but you will be able to convert them back to a date if necessary .

Comment: If you store time in a non-time format you won't be able to directly access SQL Server's [time functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186724.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I've added a comment about this @destination-data

Answer (score 4):

I think when you need only hour and minute use two columns for each one instead like this:

```
Hour tinyint
Minute tinyint
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'HH:mm')
```

Answer (score 1):

It is always stored the only thing you can do is to edit the value before it gets posted so the seconds (and also the milliseconds which are also stored) are set to 0.

I do this in my c# application where all inserts end updates are passing through one routine that checks for datetime datatype and then filters out the milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate suggestion if performance is important:

```
SELECT CONVERT([varchar](5),GETDATE(),(108))
```

Same result but much faster than FORMAT

If display with second is required again:

```
SELECT (CONVERT([varchar](5),GETDATE(),(108))+':00')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).